# Splitting series with single column that contains list, into multiple columns with single values

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `Series` object which I have pulled from a dataframe, for example through:

```
columns = list(df)
for col in columns:
    s = df[col] # The series object
```

The Series contains a `<class 'list'>` in each row, making it look like this:

```
0       [116, 66]
2       [116, 66]
4       [116, 66]
6       [116, 66]
8       [116, 66]
          ...
1498    [117, 66]
1500    [117, 66]
1502    [117, 66]
1504    [117, 66]
1506    [117, 66]
```

How could I split this up, so it becomes two columns in the Series instead?

```
0       116   66
2       116   66
          ...
1506    116   66
```

And then append it back to the original `df`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())`?

Comment: @Ch3steR that works! But how can i retain the name of the original column? It just splits the list up into two columns named `0` and `1`.

Comment: Since it's a Series it only has one name, how would you want to rename the second columns?

Comment: @rshah, ``pd.DataFrame(s.to_list(), columns=['a','b'])``

Comment: @Sushanth It solves the problem but have to rewrite column names manually every time, would be difficult if the inner lists are longer. If OP provides more details on how go about column names may be we can come up with something dynamic ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR I have posted an answer which is dynamic ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster)'s comment of using `pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())`, I managed to get the answer I was looking for, including renaming the columns in the new dataframe to also include the column name of the existing Series.

```
columns = list(df)
for col in columns:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist())
    df2.columns = [col+"_"+str(y) for y in range(len(df2.columns))]
    print(df2)
```

To keep this shorter, as also suggested by [Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster), we can simplify the above to:

```
columns = list(df)
for col in columns:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col)
    print(df2)
```

Which in my case, gives the following output:

```
     FrameLen_0  FrameLen_1 
0           116          66
1           116          66
2           116          66
3           116          66
4           116          66
..          ...         ...
749         117          66
750         117          66
751         117          66
752         117          66
753         117          66
```

Comment: `df2.columns = [col+"_"+str(y) for y in range(len(df2.columns))]` You dont need this, use `df.add_prefix` here i.e `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col)`

Comment: Whats the shape of your `df`? Can you post `df.to_dict()` to the question? (If the `df` is large `df.head(10).to_dict()`) So we can come up with solution without `for-loop`

Comment: In this small example my df has shape `(754, 15)` but the true dataset I have has the shape `(83292, 15)`

Comment: `df.head(10).to_dict()` post this then, would only 1st 10 rows' data.